# HorizontallScrollView with auto-fitting pages

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to create a HorizontalScrollView which will be exactly 3 times the screen width. I have tried the following code, but the scrollview will not scroll. How can I set it so that the 3 LinearLayouts inside the main LinearLayout are each the width of the screen?

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true">

<!-- the container for all the pages -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="100dp"
       android:background="#000000"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Note that if I give the LinearLayouts a specific width, the scrollview does scroll, but I need each LinearLayout to have the width of the screen.

Comment: Determine the screen width programmatically and then set the width of the `LinearLayouts` to match this width. Then the container, should have `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` maybe?

Comment: @g00dy how could I determine the screen width programmatically within the xml file?

Comment: Why do you want to have it in the layout? That sounds to me like hardcoding, but it will not be the same for each device. So I guess that doing it in the code (programmatically) is the way to go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use wrap_content on your top LinearLayout, and set the width of the child LinearLayouts programmatically.